# Deciphering Why Chrome Extension API Request is Blocked/Stalled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I developed a Chrome Extension that makes an API call and expects to receive some JSON in return. This is a simple HTTP request, and if I go to the URL it's requesting, there is valid JSON.

The request:

```
$.get('https://tc.MySite.com/AtsMapping.aspx', requestObj2, (data2, status2) => { do some stuff }
```

When using this Chrome Extension from my work computer (a laptop that belongs to the "MySite" in the URL above, it works as expected. JSON is returned, my Extension does what it needs to, and all is well. It works whether I'm on my company's WiFi or another connection. The same is true of my coworkers who have tried it.

However, when we deploy the Extension to clients, they are all getting the following error in their console:
[image]

I am able to replicate that error if I use my personal laptop. Further, the network pane shows the following:
[image]

The preview and response tabs are both blank (for anyone not on a MySite laptop).

Not sure if this is relevant, but here's the timing tab as well:
[image]

I have no idea what's causing this. Any suggestions? I'm tentatively thinking this has something to do with cross-origin requests. Please advise if there's more information I can provide.

Comment: Well the first thing to do is find out what the errant JSON actually looks like.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, I should clarify. No JSON response is being received. The Preview and Response tabs are both blank.